# How to attach an UVM sequence with a particular sequencer?

Tags: system-verilog, sequences, uvm

I have 3 sequences, and 4 sequencers.

I want

1. sequencer 1 to run sequence1,
2. sequencer 2 to run sequence1,
3. sequencer 3 to run sequence2, sequence3 in serial order.
4. sequencer 4 to run sequence1, sequence2 in serial order.

One method to do so is inside the test class

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
fork
   sequence1.start(sequencer1);
   sequence1.start(sequencer2);
   begin
     sequence2.start(sequencer3);
     //wait for request....
     sequence3.start(sequencer3);
   end
   begin
     sequence2.start(sequencer4);
     //wait for req....
     sequence1.start(sequencer4);
   end
join
endtask
```

How can I do the same inside each of the sequencers, than doing inside test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is the best method of doing what you want (after raising an objection before the `fork` and dropping it after the `join`). All other methods make it difficult to add additional sequences before the `fork` or after the `join`.

You can use the uvm_config_db to set the "default_sequence" of each sequencer, but you will need to create another sequence layer for sequencer3 and 4 that starts sequence1 and 2 in the desired order. You will also need to deal with raising/lowering objections inside each default sequence.

Another option is instead of using generic sequencers, you can define a sequencer and override the run_phase to start each sequence or series of sequences.